# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' error in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I already have tried Cleaning the project and rebuilding  it also syncing project with grade files and invalidate caches / restart.

But still I am facing this error.

P.S. I am very new to android programming.

**here is my Android Manifest file .**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TextPlay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TEXTPLAY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here is my MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    int counter;
    Button add,sub;
    TextView display;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter=0;
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter++;
                display.setText("Your Total is " + counter );

            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter--;
                display.setText("Your Total is" + counter);



            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Here is my activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="Your Total Is 0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_ content"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add One"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtract One"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

**This is what my error build gradle shows.**

:app:processDebugResources
/Users/shubhangkhattar/AndroidStudioProjects/NewBoston/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml
Error:(11, 32) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap_ content').
/Users/shubhangkhattar/AndroidStudioProjects/NewBoston/app/src/main/res/layout/text.xml
Error:(16) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_orientation' in package 'android'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/shubhangkhattar/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: R is a programming language - please don't add the [R] tag for this issue.

Comment: In general it is due errors in XML. Check your xml files. Maybe the space in  `android:layout_height="wrap_ content"` of your `TextView`

Comment: hi,please add your gradle file here

Comment: try to do the following `import android.R.*;` or check your xml files if they are valid

Comment: @DarshanMistry where is the gradle file ?? Thank you :)

Comment: @Joseph82 Thankyou You solved one of the errors !! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import your R file in MainActivity.java

```
import com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.R;
```

Try to press alt + Enter on highlighted R symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Create another Class "R"

```
package com.example.asus.yourname;


public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int b1=0x7f050001;
        public static final int text1=0x7f050000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {

        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int app_name1=0x7f040003;

        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
        public static final int hello1=0x7f040002;
    }
}
```